# easy date entry in Excel

Tags: excel, date

I use a time log with split time and date.
I can format the cells with the time format 00:00 returning 18:00 when 1800 is entered.
I wonder if something similar is possible for the date format when 020521 returns 02/05/2021 after entering.

I noticed when this message is posted the backslash disappeared between 00 and :
Below my efforts, it returns the correct data to the cell but I get run time error 13 type mismatch on printdate=newdate. If I format the Excel cells to date then it gets completely messed up.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        Dim rawdate As String
        Dim newdate As String
        Dim printdate As Date
         If Target.Value <> "" Then
            Debug.Print Target.Value
            rawdate = Target.Value
            Debug.Print rawdate
            If Len(rawdate) = 6 Then
            newdate = Left(rawdate, 2) & "/" & Mid(rawdate, 3, 2) & "/20" & Right(rawdate, 2)
            Debug.Print newdate
            Else
            newdate = "0" & Left(rawdate, 1) & "/" & Mid(rawdate, 2, 2) & "/20" & Right(rawdate, 2)
            Debug.Print newdate

        End If
End If
printdate = newdate
Debug.Print printdate
Target.Value = printdate

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want the user to enter datr/time in a format that Excel does not recognize as date, the you can use a VBA Change event to convert the entered data to a date

Comment: I enter the current date and time into cells that start formatted general using ctrl&; for the date and cmnd&; for the time. Once entered the date cell gets to be date formatted and the time cell custom...